# MySQL: Remove row from join view with/without touching rows in underlaying tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view, relational-database

**I've got:** a view which I create by joining two tables

```
CREATE  VIEW my_view AS
SELECT t1.id as id, t2.field, [another fields]
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
JOIN t1.id = t2.table1_id
```

Moreover, `table1` and `table2` are referenced from many other tables.

**I want:** `DELETE FROM my_view WHERE id = @id;`

**Problem:** `Can not delete from join view 'my_view' message`

**Questions:**

1. *Can I delete row from `my_view` without deleting related rows from `table1` and `table2`?*
2. *Can I delete row from `my_view` with deleting related row from `table1` but not deleting related row from `table12`?*

Comment: NO, try deleting from the original table. deleting from may result in undesired situation.

Comment: @Rahul more details please. Deleting from where may result undesirable situation? Why? What do you mean by original table?

Comment: @V_B...I guess Rahul means deleting from the underlying table on which the view is defined is the right approach.

Comment: if you delete from view and say you want to delete from table1; it may happen that you end up deleting row from table2. that, I am saying as undesired result. Delete from the original table instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can I delete row from my_view without deleting related rows from table1 and table2?

No, a view doesn't remember anything by itself, it can be seen as a saved query against `table1` and `table2`. If you want to delete a value from the view, it must also be deleted (or otherwise marked as not showing up in the view query) in the underlying tables.

> 2) Can I delete row from my_view with deleting related row from table1 but not deleting related row from table12?

You cannot do that through the view (DELETE against multi-table updatable views is not supported in MySQL), but you can of course delete the data directly in `table1` and the view will reflect the changes immediately.

Comment: suppose I delete row from `table1` but don't delete related row from `table2`. How does the view reflects the changes. I mean does it fullfil fields of `table1` with null or does it ermove the row?

Comment: @V_B Your join will not include rows in table2 which don't have a corresponding row in table1, so the row will no longer show up in the view.

Comment: I simplified the query. Actually my `JOIN` consists of 4 tables (`table1`, `table2`, `table3`, `table4`). Do you mean that if I delete the row from `table1`, all rows from `my_view` which contains that `table1` row data will be removed?

Comment: @V_B It depends on the query, but if the view uses an inner join with `table1`, the rows that are removed in table1 should remove the corresponding row from the view.

Answer (score 1):

The value that a view name means in an expression is calculated according to the view definition expression. (Unless it is a "materialized view", which is not a "view".) So updating it is taken to mean doing something to the tables used to define it.

Some views lose information: different inputs could give the same output. So if you try to give a new value that you want it to evaluate to with the idea that the tables defining it be set by the DBMS to appropriate new values then it might be ambiguous what new table values would give the new view value.

Some views are updatable in that sense, especially taking keys (and unique subrows) and foreign keys into account, not to mention other constraints. And a DBMS can easily figure out some of those, and a really smart DBMS more, but in mostly it can't be figured out and/or it's ambiguous. But you can set the tables individually.

Also, a DBMS can just say how it's going to update the inputs underlying certain views in terms of the old input values and the view expression and the update command argument. Maybe it picks certain values for the tables forming the view even when more than one possibility is consistent with the new value. Maybe it just sets those tables to some new values based on the old values and the update arguments and when you re-calculate the view from them it doesn't even get the value it would have if you had done that update to a base table. If that kind of arbitrary disambiguating choice gives you the update you need, you can request it; otherwise update the tables mentioned in the view separately.

The SQL standard actually requires that the DBMS update some views, and (obscurely) defines various categories of updatable view. Various effects of view update described by the standard are as described above. Also there are views that a DBMS can easily see to be updatable that aren't required to be by SQL.

Vendors will make their own choices. Eg [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html). (Which you, too, could have googled.) Read it. In particular, "there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table". So Q1: No, you can't update the view only; the view name will give the value from re-evaluating its expression. And Q2: No you can't update a multi-table view.

However, you can always update a view by updating the underlying tables.